# Using Formatters in Smart Table

Tags: annotations, odata, sapui5

I am currently using a smart table for building the UI and displaying items. However there is a particular field that I want to apply formatter on.

Is there anyway to specify the formatting conditions in the annotations itself?
If there is not, how do I use a formatter in a smart table?

Thanks